# How to achieve this mark style (text labels overlaying an image, with lines pointing to different details) in css/html?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing a website and trying to achieve the following style with HTML and CSS, to mark a location in an image (as the yellow mark in the screenshot):

Text labels overlaying an image, with lines pointing to different details.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to achieve this. You could use a canvas to draw the lines over the image, for example. But here's a pure CSS solution as requested, using `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. You can use the `width` and `transform` properties to control where the line is pointing.

**Update:** I updated the code to simplify having labels pointing left or right.

```css
.image-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 184px;
  background-image: url(//placekitten.com/600/200?image=7);
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
}

.label::before,
.label::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  border-top: solid yellow 1px;
}

.label::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.label-pointing-right::after {
  transform-origin: top left;
  left: 100%;
}

.label-pointing-left::after {
  transform-origin: top right;
  right: 100%;
}

.label-eye {
  transform: translate(70px, 70px);
}

.label-eye::after {
  width: 152px;
  transform: rotate(8.5deg);
}

.label-nose {
  transform: translate(420px, 150px);
}

.label-nose::after {
  width: 142px;
  border-top: solid yellow 1px;
  transform: rotate(16deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <span class="label label-pointing-right label-eye">小猫的眼睛</span>
  <span class="label label-pointing-left label-nose">小猫的鼻子</span>
</div>
```